# Different behavior when double click on jar and run same jar from command prompt on mac

Tags: java, encoding, filenotfoundexception, jfilechooser

My code is behaving very strangely on Mac OS X 10.8.2. I have a folder called "Horváth József" which has some special characters in its name. I want to view this folder with a `JFileChooser`. When I run my program by double-clicking on the JAR, it does not show all the folders which have special char in their names, but when I run the same program from the command prompt with `java -jar test.jar`, it shows me all the folders including the folder with a special name.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Encoding {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } 
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}
```

There is a folder `DKF}æßj` with special characters in its name. It doesn't show up in the file chooser, and when I try to read with the FILE type, it is not identified as a Directory as well as a File - I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Does launching the JAR from the command line run the JAR in a different way than double-clicking on the JAR?
I am using Java 7u17.